# ng-show directive returning correct but empty <img> only on device

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've seen a few answers to questions like this, but nothing seems to be working.

I have a images in an `ion-list` that are supposed to be accessed by my Ionic application using the `ng-show` Angular directive. Running locally on my machine, these load up perfectly. When deployed to my iPhone 5s however, all that is shown is a bunch of empty images. In my tests, I have also included a second set that should do the same, placed outside of `<i>` tags and using `ng-src` instead of `src` and `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

Nothing works. Here is the current HTML:

```
<img class="padding-basic-right" ng-src="img/love.png" width="48px" ng-if="track.loved">
<img class="padding-basic-right" ng-src="img/skip.png" width="48px" ng-if="!track.loved">

<i class="icon icon-accessory">
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/love.png" width="48px" ng-show="track.loved">
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/skip.png" width="48px" ng-show="!track.loved">
</i>
```

[image: View on iOS Device (iOS 9.3)]
[image: View on Safari 9.1]

I've been struggling with this for the better part of a day and I've been fixing much bigger problems than this in that time. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: not using PNGs. Apparently `ng-show` will not render PNG files, but is happy to do so with JPGs and SVGs.

Confused, but it's fixed now.